# sort array of objects by order of the property in a fixed format

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, ecmascript-2016, arrayobject

I need to sort an array of object  by property with the following order.
For the first item in the list: it is either Camel or Absolute
For the second item in the list: it has to be Dream,
For the third item in the list: it has to be Carnival

```
[Camel, Dream, Carnival] or [Absolute,  Dream, Carnival]
```

Example 1:  Given

```
 var items = [
     { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3, ... },
     { 'Name':'Camel', 'TypeId':55, ... },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4 , ...},
    ]
```

it should return:

```
var itemsSorted = [{ 'Name':'Camel', 'TypeId':55, ... },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4, ... },
    { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3, ... }]
```

Example 2: given

```
   var items = [
     { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3, ... },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4 , ...},
    { 'Name':'Absolute', 'TypeId':114 , ...}]
```

it should return:

```
   var itemsSorted = [{ 'Name':'Absolute', 'TypeId':114, ... },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4, ... },
     { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3, ... }]
```

My attempt which works, but I am wondering if there are any other solutions that is more elegant that you could recommend?

```
private _setUpdateProgress() {
   const order = ['Camel', 'Absolute', 'Dream', 'Carnival'];
   this.itemsSorted = [];

   if (this.items?.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (i === 1) {
          continue;
        }
        let info!: Array<any>;
        if (i === 0) {
          info = items.filter(x => x.Name === 
              order[0] || x.Name === order[1]);
        }
        if (i > 1) {
          info = items.filter(x => x.Name=== 
              order[i]);
        }
        this.itemsSorted.push(info[0]);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a more elegant solution for sorting the array of objects based on a specific order, you can utilize a custom sorting function that  maps the names to their desired positions. This approach leverages the `sort()` function and a predefined order map, making it concise and readable.

Here's an example:

```js
function sortItems(items) {
  const orderMap = {
    'Camel': 1,
    'Absolute': 1,
    'Dream': 2,
    'Carnival': 3
  };

  return items.sort((a, b) => {
    let orderA = orderMap[a.Name] || Number.MAX_VALUE;
    let orderB = orderMap[b.Name] || Number.MAX_VALUE;

    // Handle tie-breaker for 'Camel' and 'Absolute'
    if (orderA === orderB && orderA === 1) {
      return a.Name === 'Camel' ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return orderA - orderB;
  });
}

// Example usage
var items = [{
    'Name': 'Carnival',
    'TypeId': 3
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Camel',
    'TypeId': 55
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Dream',
    'TypeId': 4
  }
];

var itemsSorted = sortItems(items);
console.log(itemsSorted);
```

This solution uses a custom sorting function with a predefined `orderMap` to sort the array of objects. It handles the special case for 'Camel'  and 'Absolute' with a tie-breaker. This approach is more concise and  maintainable compared to manually iterating and filtering the array.

Comment: Can you explain the tie-breaking code? Why not just assign different orders to the two values?

Comment: The tie-breaker logic for 'Camel' and 'Absolute' is to handle a specific case where both 'Camel' and 'Absolute' share the same initial order position (1 in this case). This is because, according to OP requirements, either 'Camel' or 'Absolute' could be the first item in the sorted list, but 'Camel' takes precedence when both are present. If we assigned different fixed orders, we would be choosing one to always come before the other, which would not align with the flexibility of the requirement.

Comment: What's the difference between "*'Camel' takes precedence when both are present*" and "*choosing [Camel] to always come before [Absolute]*"? Can you share an input where it results in a different output?

Comment: Not knowing ahead of time. Unless I understood it wrong? It's possible. I'm all for @trincot's solution as I've tried both.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an object that maps these strings to numbers, and then use the `sort` callback to compare these numbers:

```js
const order = { "Camel": 1, "Absolute": 2, "Dream": 3, "Carnival": 4 };

const mySort = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => order[a.Name] - order[b.Name]); 

// Example runs
var items = [
    { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3,  },
    { 'Name':'Camel', 'TypeId':55,  },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4 , },
];
console.log(mySort(items));

items = [
    { 'Name':'Carnival', 'TypeId':3, },
    { 'Name':'Dream', 'TypeId':4 , },
    { 'Name':'Absolute', 'TypeId':114 , }
];
console.log(mySort(items));
```

Comment: `const order = Obect.fromEntries(['Camel', 'Absolute', 'Dream', 'Carnival'].map((name, i) => [name, i]))`